# can anyone suggest good document to learn batch apex? That has in depth details about all database class methods?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, database

I have looked through several blogs and couldn't find a detailed document that includes all methods of `Database` class. I could only get detail of `start`, `execute` and `finish`. I am interested in details about `Database.BatchableContext`, `Database`, `Database.Batchable`, `update` and every other that exists for that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't go to blogs for this kind of thing, go straight to the source: documentation! Batch apex is well documented. Start with the linked references in the `Apex Developer Guide` and work through the relevant Trailhead modules. Here are some references you should examine:

- **[Database Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)**

  > - **executeBatch(batchClassObject)**
  >     Submits a batch Apex job for execution corresponding to the specified class.
  > - **executeBatch(batchClassObject, scope)**
  >     Submits a batch Apex job for execution using the specified class and scope.
- **[Batchable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm)**

  > - **execute(jobId, recordList)**
  >     Gets invoked when the batch job executes and operates on one batch of records. Contains or calls the main execution logic for the batch job.
  > - **finish(jobId)**
  >     Gets invoked when the batch job finishes. Place any clean up code in this method.
  > - **start(jobId)**
  >     Gets invoked when the batch job starts. Returns the record set as an iterable that will be batched for execution.
  > - **start(jobId)**
  >     Gets invoked when the batch job starts. Returns the record set as a QueryLocator object that will be batched for execution.
- **[BatchableContext Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchablecontext.htm)**

  You'll likely never need to call the methods on this parameter, but it has two:

  > - **getChildJobId()**
  >     Returns the ID of the current batch job chunk that is being processed.
  > - **getJobId()**
  >     Returns the batch job ID.
- **[Using Batch Apex Unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch?id=asynchronous_apex)**

Comment: I am getting this error. "Sorry, the document you are looking for doesn't exist or could not be retrieved." while opening Developer guide that you suggested. 
However I didn't think about trail head, looks like good information there. Thanks I will start with trailhead. Are yo facing the same error while opening developer guide too?

Comment: Trailhead is *always* a good place to start. I am not getting that error, but try googling it yourself. Either just search `Database methods apex` or even just `Apex Developer Guide`, and then use the search functionality within the developer guide.

Comment: Yup, I could download the PDF and can refer to that now, Excellent source of information there. Thank You.